# Web api Multipart form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
public string Post(Model model){

}
```

`Model` contains an `IList<HttpPostedFileBase>` of files.

Is it possible to send data and file to this endpoint and bind data to model via action parameter(s)?

Comment: What type of client?  Do you you have something up and running now, even if it's not working?  It'd be helpful to include that in your post.

Comment: I just want to send file with json and i dont want to read that file or data from HttpContext ... Client is browser

Comment: You say "i dont want to read that file or data from HttpContext" - why not?

Comment: because in my model i have List wich contains list but when i 'm reading data from content it return namevalue collection so i have to use reflection for mapping data to my object but i want auto mapping

Comment: problem ist that i have to write such names  in html name="[StudentList][0][student][name]" then it will come as key in for namevalucollection so i have to use reflection it's not good for me to use reflection